# How to add array values

Tags: java, arrays, addition

How do I add an array with several methods together

```
public void inputArray() {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the number of invoices: ");
    numInvoices = keyboard.nextInt();   

Invoices = new Invoice[numInvoices];
int BillTotal = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < numInvoices; i++){
    Invoices[i] = new Invoice();
    Invoices[i].setCompanyNameFromUser();
    Invoices[i].setBillAmountFromUser();
    Invoices[i].SetDateFromUser();

    BillTotal = BillTotal + Invoices[i].setBillAmountFromUser;
```

In this case I want to add up the values input by the user in the setBillAmountFromUser method.

Answer (score 0):

This program block may help you

```
 public void inputArray() 
    {
     Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
     System.out.println("Please enter the number of invoices: ");
     int numInvoices = keyboard.nextInt();   
     int BillTotal=0;
     Invoice Invoices[numInVoices];
        for(int i=0;i<numInVoices;i++)
           {
            Invoices[i]=new Invoices();/*Your Code*/
           BillTotal+=Invoices[i].setBillAmountFromUser();
           }
    System.out.println("BillTotal="+BillTotal);
    }

    public int setBillAmountFromUser()/*Example Code block/*
    {
    /*your code */
    return 5;//Example Return value
    }
```